# tcp packets are appended is there any case only part of a packet will be read? C#

Tags: c#, networking, tcp

I wrote a parser to parse the data I get in TCP read since even when sending multiple packets theyt may get in one read, my question is if once packet might be read in 2 read commands or if I read some of the data of the packet it means all packet data is available and will be read in the same call?

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you are asking. Can you provide some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a pice of code would be nice to be sure, but i think you are talking about the data you receive through a tcp socket ... in that case the answer is: no, you won't see the contents of a packet while it's beeing read by the network device ... you get it once it has passed through the TCP stack which checks the checksum of a packet ... you wont get the data before the checksum was verified, therefore the smallest piece of data you can get is the contents of one complete packet

Answer (score 0):

TCP is a stream - only the IP layer beneath divides it into individual packets. You call `Send()` or similar API, and then the IP layer divides the stream into packets any way it sees fit. So, you can't rely on whole buffers arriving in one call.

Or, to explain with an extreme example: Imagine you call `Send(huge_1GB_buffer)`. How would you expect the read to behave?